# Trying to use the authorized_key module to allow one remote server to log into 3 other remote servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible

I am trying to use the aurthorized_key ansible module to insert my jump ec2 instances public key (id_rsa.pub)  into the autorized key file of 3 other remote servers in order for me to log into them. but I keep getting this error :

```
WARNING]: Unable to find '/home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)
[WARNING]: Unable to find '/home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)
fatal: [dev]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"}
fatal: [prod]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"}
[WARNING]: Unable to find '/home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)
fatal: [jenkins]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"}
[WARNING]: Unable to find '/home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)
fatal: [jump]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"}
```

Here is my ansible playbook:

```
tasks:
  - name: Set hostname
    hostname:
      name:   "{{inventory_hostname}}"


  - openssh_keypair:
      path: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    when: inventory_hostname == 'jump'


  - name: Fetching file to install ssh keys
    fetch:
      src: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
      dest: /tmp/id_rsa.pub

  - name: Set authorized key taken from file
    authorized_key:
      user: jump
      state: present
      key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expecting `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to be on your local machine (the one running ansible) with readable permissions by the current user.

It seems you have a condition for the first task for if the hostname is "jump", and then continue assuming the file is there for other tasks.

Confirm the following:

- All hostnames except `jump` have a pub key in the path `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.
- There is a resolveable hostname of `jump`.

Also as a recommendation, if you're generating this all the time but it should be the same key maybe take a look at storing the content securely in an [Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html)

Comment: No. /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub is not on my local machine it's on my ec2 instance named "jump" which is remote. I was thinking that the open_ssh module would store the jump public key in the /tmp/id_rsa.pub in the fetch module THEN the authorized_key module would insert it into the other machines authorized_key files.

Comment: Hi, this will only fetch if the current ansible targets name is `jump`. As recommended, store the content in Ansible Vault. That way you never need worry about fetching from remote hosts.

Comment: I'm a newbie in using ansible. This is just for one project. Is there an alternative to using the Ansible Vault?

Comment: Ansible Vault is not an alternative :). Basically it allows you to store secrets in an encrypted file and then allows their usage in a playbook

Comment: Its required in order for me to used the authorized_key module?

Comment: Hi, no it isn't required. It'll just make it a bit easier than relying on a file existing on a random server.

Answer (score 0):

> I figured it out. It was the openssh_keypair module. The path was
>   incorrect but I fixed it path: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa not 
>   id_rsa.pub.
>
> - openssh_keypair:
>           path: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa
>         when: inventory_hostname == 'jump'
>
>   - name: Fetching file to install ssh keys
>       fetch:
>         src: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
>         dest: /tmp/id_rsa.pub
>         flat: yes
>       when: inventory_hostname == 'jump'
>   - name: Set authorized key taken from file
>       authorized_key:
>         user: ec2-user
>         state: present
>         key: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/id_rsa.pub') }}"